# close does not seem to work with WebSocket

Tags: javascript, ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I have this simple javascript code :

```
window.ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/');

ws.onopen = function() { 
  ws.send('hello');
}
```

And a server in Ruby like this :

```
require 'em-websocket'

class Websocket
  def run
    EventMachine.run do

      EM::WebSocket.start(host: '0.0.0.0', port: '8000') do |ws|
        ws.onopen do |handshake|
          puts "Connected"
        end

        ws.onclose do
          puts "Closed"
        end

        ws.onmessage do |msg|
          p msg
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When a connection is close, the server should print "Closed".
In the browser, when I do `window.ws.close()`, nothing is received by the server, but when I reload the page, it print the message.

Is there a way to force the client to say than the connection is closed?

Comment: Both the client side and the server code works perfectly on my machine (running the server on MacOS with Ruby 2.2.2 and using safari as the websocket client)... although the code was missing one `end` keyword and the `Websocket.new.run` line at the end.

Comment: Strange ... I corrected the missing end. This is a copy/paste error. Can you try with firefox or chrome? Thanks.

Comment: Works for me also with Chrome and Firefox (Chrome insisted I would try it only when visiting an 'insecure' site, since the websocket connection wasn't encrypted)... does your websocket print the `"hello"` string when the message event is fired?

Comment: Try installing the [plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) gem and running this in the terminal: `ruby -e "require 'plezi'; class Ctrl; def on_open; puts 'Connected' end; def on_message data; p data end; def on_close; puts 'Closed' end; end; listen port: 8000; route '/', Ctrl;" ` It's the same websocket implementation a little condensed... what version of Ruby and what OS are you running?

Comment: I have the same behaviour with your implementation. I did a docker container. You can see it here : https://hub.docker.com/r/gcorbel/optikcaminterface_web/. This is ruby 2.2.2 and a debian wheezy.

Comment: @Myst, it seems to be a problem of Docker. It's always a problem of Docker... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer since the issue was discovered to be related to the usage of 'Docker' and a new question was posted relating to the actual issue.

This answer should (hopefully) correctly mark this question as no longer in need of attention, so that the community can focus on unanswered questions.

See the comments to the question for further details.