# Can close properly a websocket with docker

Tags: websocket, docker

This question relation is related to this other : [close does not seem to work with WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857811/close-does-not-seem-to-work-with-websocket). I don't want to do a copy/paste so you can go to the other question to have details about the code.

I run a program with Websocket on docker. It allows connections but when I do `window.ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/'); ws.close();` , the server seems to not be notified than the client has closed. When I run the same code without docker, it works.

This is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM ruby:2.2.2

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev xvfb

RUN mkdir /app

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

ONBUILD RUN chown -R app /app

RUN gem install bundler

RUN cd /app

RUN bundle install

ONBUILD EXPOSE 3000 8000
```

And this is my docker-compose file :

```
db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "15432:5432"
web:
  image: gcorbel/optikcaminterface_web
  command: ruby app.rb
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  environment:
    RACK_ENV: development
  links:
    - db
test:
  image: gcorbel/optikcaminterface_web
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  command: rspec
  environment:
    RACK_ENV: test
  links:
    - db
ws:
  image: gcorbel/optikcaminterface_web
  command: ruby websocket.rb
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
```

I run my server with `docker-compose up ws`.

Is there a problem between Docker and Websockets ?